# How do I pass a column to a function in Excel to be used as an array?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I need to pass a column to a function in Excel to perform some calculations over its values.
Basically I would like to convert a column of values inside my Excel file into an array to be used inside a VBA function.

A simple example would be writing a function to sum the values of some cells like shown in the image.
The function I was thinking of looks like this:

```
Function sum_items(A)
    Total = 0
    
    For i = 0 To UBound(A)
        Total = Total + A(i)
    Next
    
    sum_items = Total
End Function
```

Of course, once I recall the function in my Excel file it doesn't work. How can I pass a range of cells to my function?

Thank you for your help.
Yuri

Comment: As a `Range` parameter.

Comment: Importantly, note that the `.Value` of a multi-cell `Range` is a 2D array, not a 1D array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a `Range` as a `Variant` argument in your function like this.

```
Sub test()
  Dim v As Boolean
  v = passRangeAsArray(Application.Transpose(Range("A1:A5")))

End Sub

Function passRangeAsArray(r As Variant) As Boolean
  
  Dim i As Long
  
  For i = LBound(r) To UBound(r)
    Debug.Print r(i)
  Next
  passRangeAsArray = True
End Function
```

Take note that for simplicity, I transposed the range before passing it to the funtion. The reason is when you pass or assign a `Range` to a `Variant`, it produces a 2D array and you will have to make some more test to iterate to the array correctly. HTH.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your kind answer.
Through your suggestion I could write a function which does what I was expecting it to do.

Function passRangeAsArray(r As Range)
  s = Application.Transpose(r)
  
  Dim i As Long
  tot = 0
  
  For i = LBound(s) To UBound(s)
    tot = tot + s(i)
  Next
  passRangeAsArray = tot
End Function

Have a nice day
Yuri